# ZFS: inconsistent allocated space after changing recordsize

Tags: debian, zfs

**some info/setup:**

- pool was original created with  no datasets + default recordsize (128K) + ashift=12 + no compression + using default checksum (which I believe is fletcher4)
- I copied some videos (destination was /mnt/mystorage/myvideos) (the total size of the myvideos folder according to `du -d1 -h /mnt/mystorage` is 1TB after I'm done copying)
- After copying the videos, I then decided I want datasets (mystorage/myvideos) + recordsize=1M + lz4 compression and checksum=sha256. compression+checksum+recordsize were changed on the main pool.
- I moved /mnt/mystorage/myvideos to /mnt/mystorage/temp/myvideos to make way for mystorage/myvideos dataset.
- I created mystorage/myvideos dataset. Examining this new dataset using `zfs get all mystorage/myvideos`, compression+checksum+recordsize are inherited from the main pool.
- I then copied all the videos in /mnt/mystorage/temp/myvideos using `rsync -riv --delete --progress --size-only --stats /mnt/mystorage/temp/myvideos/ /mnt/mystorage/myvideos/`
- To verify all the files have been copied, I ran the rsync command above several times. No further files were created/deleted in the destination.

**findings after I've done copying:**

- According to `du -d1 -h /mnt/mystorage`, the new myvideos folder is only 800GB instead of 1TB
- According to `zfs get compressratio mystorage/myvideos`, the compressratio is 1.00x

**Any ideas where is the "missing" 200GB?**